# To avoid over ridden of injected objects in table component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

**Scenario:**

- I have an component called `list` where i am displaying all my `customers` in the **dropdown**.
- When i choose some customers from the dropdown and click **Add** button i am adding these `selected customers(Ex customer 1 & 2)` properties(i,e email,phone,...etc) to the `table` present in **display** component and  i  am clearing the dropdown values as in  below image:

[image]

**Expected result:** When i visit the dropdown for the 2nd time and if choose `3rd & 4th` customers i should be able to add `3rd & 4th`  customers along with the  `1st & 2nd` customers like this:

[image]

Now i am adding the `3rd & 4th`  customers but it is overriding the previous customers(1st & 2nd) like this:

[image]

**But i want add new customers along with previous customer as shown in the 2nd image.**

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-wrx3yq?file=src/app/list/list.component.ts)**

Comment: Use list:addCustomer

Comment: Please stop posting questions with StackBlitz links. Your questions are required to contain all the code necessary to reproduce your problem **in the question**, not on a 3rd party code hosting site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the every selected object in the list and then use it as dataSource property:

And update the DataSource property like:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(your_list)
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <h3>Display</h3>
    <form [formGroup]="displayForm">
                                          \/
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Email Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.email}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Phone Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.phone}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Button Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="button" stickyEnd>
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        <br>
<button color="accent" mat-flat-button class="Update-btn" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>

</form>  
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ICustomer } from '../models';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css']
})
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  public contacts: ICustomer;
  public selectedCustomers: any[] = [];
  public displayForm: FormGroup;
  public addCustomer: any;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);

  list: any[] = []

  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'button'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public dataService: DataService) { }

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.displayForm = this.fb.group({
    });
    this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.CustomerIds.length; i++) {
          this.list.push(value.CustomerIds[i])
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.list)
        }
        console.log(this.list)
      }
    });
  }

  public onSave(): void {
    this.addCustomer = this.selectedCustomers;
    //console.log(this.addCustomer)
    var arr = this.addCustomer.CustomerIds.map(value => value.id);

    console.log(arr);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-dhaws2)

Comment: Your solution will add objects to the table, but how can i avoid duplicates?

Comment: and how can  i read from the table?

Comment: Check for Id in the list then add

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-dhaws2

Comment: I have one more quirement: I am trying to delete the added customer object like this: **public deleteCustomer(element): void {
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(i => i !== element)
  }** I am able to `delete` but unable add the deleted `customer` again.

Comment: this will not delete the actual object from array, this only (hide) object from list

Comment: you need to use splice with index positioin to delete! Provide current working demo will update in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188916/discussion-between-empty-soul-and-prashant-pimpale).

Answer (score 0):

You should need to check whether Object is exist or not else push like below -

```
this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.subscribe(value => { 
      if (value.CustomerIds && value.CustomerIds.length){
        if (this.selectedCustomers && this.selectedCustomers.CustomerIds) {
          value.CustomerIds.forEach(ele => {
            this.selectedCustomers.CustomerIds.findIndex(obj => obj.id == ele.id) !== -1 ?  "" : this.selectedCustomers.CustomerIds.push(ele);
          });
        } else {
          this.selectedCustomers = value;
        }
      }
    });
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-trkvlk?file=src/app/display/display.component.html)

Comment: Now i am able to add the objects only one time.

Comment: I can add only once, I cant add the customer twice.

Comment: @Empty_Soul check my updated answer

Comment: I want to display it in `table`

Comment: @Empty_Soul there must be something wrong with dataTable

Comment: I have tried your solution here:  **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-edjguf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdisplay%2Fdisplay.component.html**

Comment: You solution is working fine, but i am unable to show it in table.

Comment: Probably due to change detection view is not getting updated, can you try using another table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188873/discussion-between-empty-soul-and-pardeep-jain).